# Maintaining line breaks when writing and retrieving a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I have an application where the user can write articles and they will be displayed on a web page. Instead of storing all the text in the database I want to write it to a text file and store it that way.
The problem is, I can't seem to get the file to hold formatting ie line breaks. If the user types**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget ligula eget quam 
consectetur ornare. Integer sed sapien risus, ac tincidunt lectus. Quisque ultrices mi 
tortor. Fusce luctus magna non dolor facilisis imperdiet. Praesent tempus gravida dolor, sit amet viverra ligula vehicula sit amet.

Donec congue sodales orci, in sodales nunc fermentum quis. Proin feugiat feugiat 
ultrices. Mauris iaculis libero non nibh sagittis fermentum.
Etiam odio sapien,

pulvinar sed viverra nec, euismod eu massa. Sed pulvinar diam a velit rhoncus non 
iaculis mi facilisis.

**and then saves, it is saved as**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget ligula eget quam 
consectetur ornare. Integer sed sapien risus, ac tincidunt lectus. Quisque ultrices mi 
tortor. Fusce luctus magna non dolor facilisis imperdiet. Praesent tempus gravida dolor, sit amet viverra ligula vehicula sit amet. Donec congue sodales orci, in sodales nunc fermentum quis. Proin feugiat feugiat ultrices. Mauris iaculis libero non nibh sagittis fermentum.Etiam odio sapien, pulvinar sed viverra nec, euismod eu massa. Sed pulvinar diam a velit rhoncus non 
iaculis mi facilisis.

**Is there any way to maintain formatting?**

Current code is

```
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/Articles/" + articlePost.atclFile + ".txt"));
articleTextbox.Text = fileContents.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Comment: @AustinSalonen eddited to show code

Comment: What is `articleTextbox`? A textbox?

Comment: Hi it was a literal. I got the solution thought. Mikes solution worked. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
articleTextbox.Text = fileContents.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

or

```
articleTextbox.Text = fileContents.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Comment: You should just use `System.Environment.NewLine` instead of the escapes (\n and \r\n). More portable that way.

Comment: This solution worked for me but for some reason Envirorment.NewLine did not

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace text line breaks with HTML line breaks:

```
var newText = oldText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Comment: Can ya look at my code and see if you can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

how about the good old

```
     <pre> ... </pre>
```